# If $X$ and $X^2$ are identically distributed then $X \in \{0,1\} $ almost surely

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

If a random variable $X$ is identically distributed to its square than it is almost surely non-negative, further for the distribution function it follows, that $F_X(x)\overset{id}{=} F_{X^2}(x)= F_X(\sqrt{x})$, so iteratively applied, one get $F_X(x)= F_X(x^{1/2n}) $ so in the limit $ n \to \infty $ we get $F_X(x) =F_X(1) \Leftrightarrow P(X\in [0, x])= P(X\in [0,1])$. Further, for the survival function we have $P(X\in (x,\infty )) = P(X \in (1, \infty))$.
No how did we see that $P(X \in \{0,1\})=1$?
How is  $P(X \in (1, \infty))=0 $ and $P(X \in (0,1))=0$ (that $P(X<0)=0$ is clear)?

Comment: Only two numbers are equal to their own square: $0$ and $1. \qquad$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $F(x)=P(X\le x)$ be the distribution function of $X$.

Since $X^2$ is always nonnegative, $P(X^2<0)=0$. Hence $P(X<0)$ is also zero because $X^2$ and $X$ are identically distributed.

For any $x\ge0$, we have $F(x)=P(X\le x)=P(X^2\le x^2)\stackrel{(\ast)}{=}P(X\le x^2)=F(x^2)$, where the equality marked by an asterisk is due to the assumption that $X^2$ and $X$ are identically distributed. Therefore $F(x)=F(x^2)$ or equivalently, $F(\sqrt{x})=F(x)$. It follows that
$$
F(x)=\begin{cases}
F(x^2)=F(x^4)=\cdots=\lim\limits_{k\to+\infty}F(x^{2k})=F(0^+)=F(0)&\text{when }0\le x<1,\\
F(x^{1/2})=F(x^{1/4})=\cdots=\lim\limits_{k\to+\infty}F(x^{1/2k})=F(1^+)=F(1)&\text{when }x\ge1,
\end{cases}
$$
and
\begin{aligned}
P(0<X<1)&=\lim_{x\to1^-}F(x)-F(0)=F(0)-F(0)=0,\\
P(X>1)&=\lim_{x\to+\infty}F(x)-F(1)=F(1)-F(1)=0.
\end{aligned}
Hence $P(X\in\{0,1\})=1-P(X<0)-P(0<X<1)-P(X>1)=1-0-0-0=1$, i.e. $X$ is almost surely equal to $0$ or $1$.